# Respect HTML tags inside an editable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

i'm trying to realize a very simple kind of wysiwyg javascript editor.

What i have:
I know, the current Javascript doesn't work by hitting the button…

```
   wrapText = function(replacementText) {
          var range, sel;
          if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
              range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
              range.deleteContents();
              return range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
            } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
              range = document.selection.createRange();
              return range.text = replacementText;
            }
          }
        };

<a id="bold-btn">Make it Bold!</a>
<div id="editit" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Now, if you mark/highlight some text inside your editable div and hit the Make it Bold - Button. The selected text will be wrapped within a <b/> tag.

The problem is that the output seems like this:

This is a sample text with a <b>bold<b/> word.

instead of:

This is a sample text with a **bold** word.

Any idea?

Comment: And where's the code that makes it bold? How are we supposed to know what the problem is!

Comment: What does your javascript code look like?

Comment: if you don't know there are already done solutions for your problem http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: I would reckon you need to use `innerHtml` as opposed to `innerText` if that's how you're doing it.

Comment: Sorry, thought that the Javascript part isnt the problem. i'll edit the question.

Comment: edited, i guess createTextNode is the wrong part

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/style.js)'s a sample solution that works very well. Yep - just 1.5k LOC reusing next Nk LOC. There's no such thing like "very simple kind of wysiwyg javascript editor".

Comment: Should you be interested n how to do it without `execCommand`: the [`selection.surroundContents`](http://jsfiddle.net/VRcvn/) works pretty well. Caveat: it will mess up the code if the selection overlaps HTML tags partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying too hard ;)

What your code is doing is creating a text node, which means the contents will be text instead  of being treated as html.  You can just use `execCommand` for this instead.

For instance, "Make it Bold" just needs to call `document.execCommand('bold')`.
You can look at Mozilla's docs for [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) for more details.

For a really small example, take a look at the demo for [wysiwyg](https://github.com/adamsanderson/wysiwyg), and then look at `index.js` for some ideas, or just use the library yourself.